# Cannot query current user's friend list and add to listview android with parse

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, pfrelation

I've tried to to query of current user's friend list and add it to listview in android. The problem is the method keep showing errors

This is my code

```
package com.example.krisanapongpoonsawat.chatit;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<ParseUser> uList;

    /** The user. */
    public static ParseUser user;
    ArrayList<String> friendlist;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        loadUserList();

    }
    private void loadUserList()
    {
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Friends");
        query.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> friendList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + friendList.size() + " scores");
                    for (int i = 0; i < friendlist.size(); i++) {
                        Object object = friendlist.get(i);
                        String name = ((ParseObject) object).getObjectId().toString();
                        listAdapter.add(name);


                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_favorite:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
                Intent intent = new Intent(User.this, Search.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }




}
```

and the error shown is

```
    Error:(66, 51) error: <anonymous com.example.krisanapongpoonsawat.chatit.User$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(List,ParseException) in FindCallback
Error:(67, 25) error: name clash: done(List<ParseObject>,ParseException) in <anonymous com.example.krisanapongpoonsawat.chatit.User$1> and done(List<T>,ParseException) in FindCallback have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
where T is a type-variable:
T extends ParseObject declared in interface FindCallback
```

Can you solve this? I've been stuck with it for 3 days now

let me know if you need any additional info!

Thank you

Comment: Please provide Minimum, Complete and Verifiable code/example for us to reproduce the issue. See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated the code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-many-to-many) you have a lot of informations about relations

Reffering to this [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-many-to-many) and our conversation in comments, I think your query should look like that:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
query.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> friendList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + friendList.size() + " scores");
            for (int i = 0; i < friendList.size(); i++) {
                ParseObject item = friendList.get(i);
                ParseRelation<ParseObject> friendRelation = item.getRelation("Friends");
                ParseQuery friendsQuery = friendRelation.getQuery();
                findFriends(friendsQuery);
            }
         } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
    }
});

...

private void findFriends(ParseQuery query) {

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        ...

    });

}
```

It is very likely that something in my answer may not work, but I have no other idea.

Comment: I've tried it but the same error still occurs, any suggestions?

Comment: Replace `new FindCallback()` with `new FindCallback<ParseObject>()` in my answer

Comment: It didn't error now but my listview is still empty, The log.e says that I've retrieved 0 friends. Any suggestion?

Comment: What type of column is "owner" in your database?

Comment: Type String and friendlist of current user is saved in PFrelation column.

Comment: So you can use this `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()` as you had before. Or change column type to pointer to _User

Comment: Did I do the right thing? I try to query from current user's relation to get current usre's friends.

Comment: Did you tried to use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()` in `query.whereEqualTo` ? And friendList size is still 0

Comment: If you have time now, we can continue this discussion on chat:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95793/iosandroid

Comment: Yes i did that but the friendList size is still zero, any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe current user is null or don't exists in your Friends class

Comment: It does exists, I've checked with parse.com there's Friends class.

Comment: but the Friends type is Relation<Friends>

Comment: Please, join chat, I don't want spam here :)

Comment: I can't access chat my reputation is not enough

Comment: what is the name of class on Parse.com, which conatins column "owner"?

Comment: User class and the column friends is PFReation type